# Change background of spinner popup, Android 4.0

Tags: android, background, spinner, customization

I want to change the background of the popup that appears once a spinner is clicked. I looked on forums and looked in the android source, but nothing worked for me, the background is still gray as it is by default. So far I've made customizations of the popup that appears when the overflow from the actionbar is clicked and everything works as it is supposed to, but I am having trouble with this Spinner widget. Co far I've tried:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">


<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>

</style>

    <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
      <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_actinonbarstyle</item>
  </style>
```

and other combinations from what I've searched in the source. Can someone help me, with code example, how can I do this, because I'm really stuck. I'm developing my application for Android 4.0 and up. Thx

Comment: use a custom adapter i hope it will do

Comment: thx for the suggestion but i want to do it with a theme, because I want to define default style for every spinner in my application, as I already did for lot's of things.

Comment: the popup doesnt fall under spinner its an adapter , and u ll be using something like android.layout.simplespinneritem1 .. which is defined by android for the resource to inflate and ll be showing its bg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I am not sure about this answer, you can accept or ignore it.

I think this requirement can't possible through theme changes. Because Spinner constructor assigns value on popupBackground attr only if you wrote in layout xml otherwise it will use default theme value. like below :

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:popupBackground="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
```

I am attaching the spinner constructor source code, so you will get better knowledge.

```
       /**
 * Construct a new spinner with the given context's theme, the supplied attribute set,
 * and default style. <code>mode</code> may be one of {@link #MODE_DIALOG} or
 * {@link #MODE_DROPDOWN} and determines how the user will select choices from the spinner.
 *
 * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can
 *        access the current theme, resources, etc.
 * @param attrs The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
 * @param defStyle The default style to apply to this view. If 0, no style
 *        will be applied (beyond what is included in the theme). This may
 *        either be an attribute resource, whose value will be retrieved
 *        from the current theme, or an explicit style resource.
 * @param mode Constant describing how the user will select choices from the spinner.
 * 
 * @see #MODE_DIALOG
 * @see #MODE_DROPDOWN
 */
public Spinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int mode) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner, defStyle, 0);

    if (mode == MODE_THEME) {
        mode = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner_spinnerMode, MODE_DIALOG);
    }

    switch (mode) {
    case MODE_DIALOG: {
        mPopup = new DialogPopup();
        break;
    }

    case MODE_DROPDOWN: {
        DropdownPopup popup = new DropdownPopup(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mDropDownWidth = a.getLayoutDimension(
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner_dropDownWidth,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(a.getDrawable(
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner_popupBackground));
        final int verticalOffset = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner_dropDownVerticalOffset, 0);
        if (verticalOffset != 0) {
            popup.setVerticalOffset(verticalOffset);
        }

        final int horizontalOffset = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner_dropDownHorizontalOffset, 0);
        if (horizontalOffset != 0) {
            popup.setHorizontalOffset(horizontalOffset);
        }

        mPopup = popup;
        break;
    }
    }

    mGravity = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner_gravity, Gravity.CENTER);

    mPopup.setPromptText(a.getString(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner_prompt));

    mDisableChildrenWhenDisabled = a.getBoolean(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.Spinner_disableChildrenWhenDisabled, false);

    a.recycle();

    // Base constructor can call setAdapter before we initialize mPopup.
    // Finish setting things up if this happened.
    if (mTempAdapter != null) {
        mPopup.setAdapter(mTempAdapter);
        mTempAdapter = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked!! :) I was led to the theme usage because of the questions (and answers) for this kind of problem on the forums, but adding 'android:popupBackground' in xml solved it. Thank u very much.